# Python: Check if any file exists in a given directory

Tags: python, file, path, directory

Given a directory as a string, how can I find if ANY file exists in it?

```
os.path.isFile()       # only accepts a specific file path
os.listdir(dir) == []  # accepts sub-directories
```

My objective is to check if a path is devoid of files only (not sub-directories too).

Comment: In practice something like this is seldom needed since a properly written loop to process all the files of interest in a directory will just iterate 0 times if there aren't any. You want you can count them in the loop and afterward if check see how many, if any, were processed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To only check one specific directory, a solution like this would suffice:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def does_file_exist_in_dir(path):
    return any(isfile(join(path, i)) for i in listdir(path))
```

To dissect what is happening:

- The method `does_file_exist_in_dir` will take your path.
- Using [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) it will return True if a file is found by iterating through the contents of your path by calling a [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir) on it. Note the use of [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for the path in order to provide a qualified filepath name to properly check.

As an option, if you want to traverse through all sub-directories of a given path and check for files, you can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and just check to see if the level you are in contains any files like this:

```
for dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if not files:
        print("no files at this level")
```

Comment: @idjaw: os.walk() will go through all sub-directories. I'm only looking for one given path

Comment: @meestaman I was actually in the process of putting together a solution for exactly that. Hold up. :)

Comment: @idjaw: Sweet! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks idjaw. Works a charm!

Comment: Seems like `any_files = len(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*.*'))) > 0` would suffice.

Comment: @martineau I was thinking about glob too, but unfortunately that would not work if you had a filename without a '.'